# CSS: Putting div above any other element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get navigator-game-window to display above canvas element and everything else, it seems its always behind these. When I load the page I can see it on top for a split second, it then dissapears then never shows itself again.

How can I get it to run on top? I've tried changing the position but nothing I try works.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/resources/css/app.css?v={{ time() }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/resources/css/loading.css?v={{ time() }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/resources/css/design.css?v={{ time() }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.0.9/dist/tippy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.0.9/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>

    <div id="loading-screen">
        <div id="loading-images">
            <img src="/resources/images/loading-screen/13__-6PX._-69w.png">
            <img class="last-loading-image" src="/resources/images/loading-screen/photo<?php echo rand(1, 29); ?>.png">
            <img src="/resources/images/loading-screen/12__-6PX._-NC.png">
        </div>
        <p id="loading-text"></p>
        <div id="loading-bar">
            <div class="loading-bar-center"></div>
        </div>
        <p class="loading-progress-text">&nbsp;&nbsp; 76%</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="hotel-view">
            <div class="hotel-view-logo">
                <img src="/resources/images/hotel-view/reception_logo_drape.png">
            </div
            <div class="hotel-view-avatar">
                <img class="hotel-view-avatar" src="https://habboon.pw/habbo-imaging/avatarimage/figure?figure=sh-3338-93.ch-3334-93-92.lg-3337-92.hd-180-1.ha-3331-0.ca-1813-63&gesture=sml&size=m">
            </div>
        </div>
        <canvas id="game_canvas"></canvas>
        <div id="bottom-bar">
            <div class="bottom-bar-view-more-icon">
                <img src="/resources/images/bottom-bar/arrow.png">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar-home-icon">
                <img src="/resources/images/bottom-bar/house.png">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar-rooms-icon">
                <img src="/resources/images/bottom-bar/rooms.png">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar-catalog-icon">
                <img src="/resources/images/bottom-bar/catalog.png">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar-avatar">
                <img src="https://habboon.pw/habbo-imaging/avatarimage/figure?figure=sh-3338-93.ch-3334-93-92.lg-3337-92.hd-180-1.ha-3331-0.ca-1813-63&gesture=sml&size=m">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar-seperator"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="game-windows">
            <div id="navigator-game-window">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const authTicket = 'saichania123';
        const uniqueId = '{{ uniqid() }}';
        const figureCode = '';
    </script> 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js?v={{ time() }}"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/websockets.js?v={{ time() }}?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/packet_events.js?v={{ time() }}?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/packet_headers.js?v={{ time() }}?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/packets.js?v={{ time() }}?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/game.js?v={{ time() }}?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/other.js?v={{ time() }}?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#loading-screen {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0E151C;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 147px;
    margin-top: -8.1px;
    margin-left: -7.7px;
}

#loading-images {
    position: relative;
}

#loading-images img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.last-loading-image{
    padding-top: 51px;
    padding-left:11px;
}

#loading-text {
    padding-top: 456.7px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size:28.1px;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
}

#loading-bar {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 392.8px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -16px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: black;
}

.loading-bar-center {
    width: 76%;
    background: #BACAD3;
    height: 8px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #8CA1AD;
}

.loading-progress-text {
    font-size: 13.5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.container {
    display: none;
}

#bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 51px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2000;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#53524f 2px,orange 2px,red 1px, transparent 0);
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #53524f;
    border-top: 1px solid #2F2F2F;
}

#bottom-bar img {
    float: left;
}

.bottom-bar-view-more-icon {
    height: 43.1px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    background-color: #3A3832;
    color: #9C9791;
    font-weight: 600;
    width:12px;
}

.bottom-bar-view-more-icon {
    margin-top: 2.4px;
    padding-left: 1.7px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.bottom-bar-view-more-icon img {
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.bottom-bar-home-icon img {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.bottom-bar-rooms-icon img {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.bottom-bar-catalog-icon img {
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 5.5px;
}

.bottom-bar-avatar {
    margin-top: -17.6px;
    margin-left: 167px;
}

.bottom-bar-avatar img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 150px, 64px, 0);
}

.bottom-bar-seperator {
    margin-left: 231px;
    width:1.4px;
    background-color: rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.308);
    height:40px;
    margin-top: 22.4px;
}
html, body, div, canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#game_canvas {
}

#hotel-view {
    background: url(http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=hd-3091-8.lg-3078-81.hr-8…wa-2005-62&action=wlk&gesture=sad&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml),url(http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/reception/val18_background_left.png),url(http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/reception/meter_level_1_vip_icon_lympix.png),url(http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/reception/background_right_easter2016.png),url(http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/reception/val18_background_gradient.png);
    background-position: 11.5% 92%, left bottom, left bottom,right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat, no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat-x,repeat-x;
    background-color: #68E5FF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 794px;
    margin-top: -38px;
}

.hotel-view-avatar {
    margin-top: 399px;
    margin-left: 120.6px;
}

.hotel-view-logo {
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#navigator-game-window, .navigator-game-window {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 51px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2001;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position: absolute or position:fixed and top:0 and left:0 for your navigator-game-window id and class css.

Hope this works. I am using stackoverflow iOS app and cannot do much of code formatting:(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking for, since I can't see what it normally looks like with the images present. But, if you're wanting #navigator-game-window to always be visible, you're going to need to use

```
#navigator-game-window {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

That positions the element at the top-left corner of the closest parent div that has relative positioning. Unless you manually set another parent as position: relative;, which you haven't, using this code will set it to align relative to the

Here's a jsfiddle with the code you provided copy-pasted into it with the necessary changes: https://jsfiddle.net/aqm2ze04/4/